# how to get data frames within lists?

Tags: r

I am using the following code to run simulations. How can I get `a` from `x1`? I have tried `lapply` below but doesn't seem to work.

```
library(parallel)
clusterEvalQ(cl,library(evir))
set.seed(0)
system.time(
 x1 <- parLapply(cl, 1:100000,
   function(i) {
       n1 <- rpois(1,4)
       n2<-  rpois(1,7)
       list(data.frame(a=rexp(n1, rate=0.1),a1=rexp(n1, rate=0.6)), 
            data.frame(b=rexp(n2, rate=0.7),b1=rexp(n2, rate=0.6)))

   }
  )
)

y1<-lapply(x1, '[', , "a")
```

Comment: Can we assume that the number of a data frame (in the case of `a` or `a1` - 1) is known? Or should we look for this column across all data frames?

Comment: @Julius we can assume it is known

Comment: `a` is not a `data.frame` it's a `vector` within a data.frame. The same is true of `b`... You don't understand the data structures you're working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y1 <- lapply(x1, function(x) x[[1]][["a"]])
```

gives a required list of vector assuming that the number of a data frame is known and equals 1. More generally:

```
y1 <- Filter(Negate(is.null), sapply(unlist(x1, rec = FALSE), `[[`, "a"))
```

Comment: thanks, i slightly changed the code above. How can I get only `a` or  `a1`.